# Changing Composite Audit Log via commands

Tags: python, soa, composite, weblogic11g, wlst

In weblogic Server 11g, is it possible to change the Composite Audit Level via commands ?

I was able to find some SOA Composite Application Management Commands which helped me create a python script to perform various action on the composites.  PFB the commands:
sca_startComposite
sca_stopComposite
sca_activateComposite
sca_retireComposite
sca_assignDefaultComposite
sca_getDefaultCompositeRevision
sca_listDeployedComposites

Do we have any command which can be used to switch the Composite Audit Level between production, Off, Development and inherit ?